# Converting JSON to HTML in an angular.js app

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, node.js

I have an app which is supposed to display book like data (although will also have some interactive content such as quizzes). I am storing the pages as xml, as something like

```
<page>
  <image>http://someimage</image>
  <text>bla bla bla </text>
  <text>hello there </text>
  <image></image>
  <quiz type="multichoice">
    <question>What is the first letter of the alphabet</question>
    <answer>a</answer>
    <answer>b</answer>
    <answer>c</answer>
  </quiz>
</page>
```

And there is no restriction on the order or amount of elements on a given page. On my web server, I am converting these to a javascript object (and caching it). All is good until this point.

But what I want is for the client to then be able to request a page, and have logic to convert the javascript object into HTML. What I cannot figure out is how to write this logic with angular.js. I cannot see an obvious way of doing it - ng-repeat would only work if I wanted the same HTML for every element. But in this case I would want to display an image as an image, text as a paragraph, and quiz as something more complex. With jade templating, this would be trivial.

I want to have something working quickly, and am concerned that the learning curve of angular is going to be a time waster. Doing this with jade templating would be trivial, but of course has the downside of being server side.

Some clarification: I know how to get the data to the client, that just requires using $http. But what I don't understand at all is how to actually do what I want with the data once it is actually at the client. Whether it is JSON or XML is irrelevant. I just need to know how to write code that will dynamically add html elements to the view, based on what is in the data.

Comment: You're essentially asking 1. how do I do <general thing> with angular (check out custom directives), and 2. how subjectively steep will the learning curve feel for you when learning angular compared to how easy it would be for you to accomplish it with some technology you are already familiar with (jade -.which by the way serves a different purpose; server side template creation vs. client side responsiveness).  Yes, there may be some overlap, but that's like asking how much you'll *really* like apples, because you already know you like oranges and apples *just couldn't* be as good.

Comment: It's not a general thing. All the tutorials I've looked at assume static html, but that the model changes, but still needs the same html.

Comment: You don't reference any tutorials, or examples of what you've tried.  I would expect to see an example with a custom directive, `restrict: 'E'` somewhere, either `template: <div>...</div>` or `templateUrl: 'myCustControlTemplate.html'`... something like that, and what the result of that effort was.  Directives, that's the Angular term for what you're trying to accomplish.  You would have a directive that maps an `<image>` to HTML `<img>` for example.

Comment: But that isn't at all what I want to do. There happens to be a 1 to 1 mapping between image and img, which is great in that case.

But the HTML I want to generate for the question, for example, would be a lot more complex.

I think Angular is completely the wrong technology for what I am trying to do, which is why this doesn't make sense to anybody. I will look into something else.

Comment: I was just pointing you in the right direction, and giving a basic example of what directives are used for, in response to the vague, do-this-work-for-me "question".  Here's a link to a tutorial for dynamic directives: http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/  and one on nested directives... http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/06/24/nested-recursive-directives-in-angular/

Answer (score 0):

You need something "working quickly" when you already are familiar with a technology for which achieving results will be "trivial".  You've answered your own question - go with what you know.

Angular is just a tool, it takes time to learn and upon doing so you can accomplish things.  It can solve your problem, but you'll need to learn it first.  Even if you get some good answers as to how this particular problem might be solved with Angular, you will still need to understand how to develop and deploy an angular application, which will not be as trivial as using what you already know.

Answer (score -1):

Get the XML data to the client using http. Parse the xml.

```
angular.module('app').controller('TestController', function($scope, $http){
//use $http here
$http.get('https://stackoverflow.com').then(function(successResponse){
   $scope.data = successResponse;
}, function(errorRepsonse){
   $scope.error = errorRepsonse;
});
```

});

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. I know how to parse xml. I don't know how to generate html based on my xml in angular.js.